# DateTime conversion to User Timezone - Odoo Website

Tags: odoo-10

I'm trying to display datetime field value in odoo website , it works using t-field and t-field-options inside span,

but i need to show as editable field in form inside input field, how to show field datetime to user timezone in input value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScript

```xml
<field id="user_date" name="date" />
<script>
  document.getElementById("user_date").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```